# Blueimp - disable delete button for previously uploaded images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, blueimp

When I upload the files via blueimp upload script, the file information is stored in data table along with upload timestamp. Now, when I am editing the form, the files appear again.

I want to do a simple thing... if the current timestamp is less than the file timestamp (previously uploaded), then the delete button will be disabled.

For that reason, I need to use Ajax to validate it. But nothing seems to be working within the `<script type='text/x-tmpl'></script>` tags.

I have no idea what x-tmpl is. I searched the web and found it is some kind of template. Is it possible to use javascript with these x-tmpl?

---

I want to do something like the following:

```x-tmpl
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var checkAvailability = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "request.php?file="+{% file.deleteUrl %},
            dataType: 'html',
            context: document.body,
            global: false,
            async:false,
            success: function(data) {
            return data;
            }
        }).responseText;
        if(!checkAvailability){
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %} DISABLED>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
        } else{
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
        }
    </script>
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% }
```

Any help or suggestions how can I use AJAX within this `x-tmpl` tags for the timestamp verification purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I know that was 2 years ago, but I've been working with the plugin and actually i did just like that:

In the html code you have a table that has the contex target, where de files are displayed right in the "files" class:

```
<table role="presentation" class="table table-striped">
    <tbody class="files"> <!-- files are displayed right here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The script text/x-tmpl is just a template of the table's rows that will receive the content and will be add to the tbody with .files class

So in the jquery file (main.js) when you load existing files, before ajax, just clean the context target like that:

```
$('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');

//clean the context target before load new files        
$('.files').html('');

$.ajax({
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('#fileupload')[0]
}).always(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done').call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
});
```

But also you can use jquery options to create a template instead of x-tmpl:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    filesContainer: $('tbody.files'),
    uploadTemplateId: null,
    downloadTemplateId: null,
    uploadTemplate: function (o) {
        var rows = $();
        $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
            var row = $('<tr class="template-upload fade">' +
                '<td><span class="preview"></span></td>' +
                '<td><p class="name"></p>' +
                '<strong class="error text-danger"></strong>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td><p class="size">Processando...</p>' +
                '<div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">' +
                '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                (!index && !o.options.autoUpload ?
                    '<button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>' +
                    '<i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>' +
                    '<span>Upload</span>' +
                    '</button>' : '') +
                (!index ? '<button class="btn btn-warning cancel">' +
                '<i class="fas fa-ban"></i>' +
                '<span>Cancelar</span>' +
                '</button>' : '') +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>');
            row.find('.name').text(file.name);
            row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
            if (file.error) {
                row.find('.error').text(file.error);
            }
            rows = rows.add(row);
        });
        return rows;
    },
    downloadTemplate: function (o) {
        var rows = $();
        $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
            var row = $('<tr class="template-download fade">' +
                '<td><span class="preview"></span></td>' +
                '<td><p class="name"></p>' +
                (file.error ? '<div><span class="badge badge-danger">Erro</span></div>' : '') +
                '</td>' +
                '<td><span class="size"></span></td>' +
                '<td>' +
                (file.deleteUrl ? '<button class="btn btn-danger delete">' +
                '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>' +
                '<span>Excluir</span>' +
                '</button>' +
                '<input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">' : '<button class="btn btn-warning cancel">' + 
                '<i class="fas fa-ban"></i>' +
                '<span>Cancelar</span>' +
                '</button>') +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>');
            row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
            if (file.error) {
                row.find('.name').text(file.name);
                row.find('.error').text(file.error);
            } else {
                row.find('.name').append($('<a></a>').text(file.name));
                if (file.thumbnailUrl) {
                    row.find('.preview').append(
                        $('<a></a>').append(
                            $('<img>').prop('src', file.thumbnailUrl)
                        )
                    );
                }
                row.find('a')
                    .attr('data-gallery', '')
                    .prop('href', file.url);
                row.find('button.delete')
                    .attr('data-type', file.deleteType)
                    .attr('data-url', file.deleteUrl);
            }
            rows = rows.add(row);
        });
        return rows;
    }
});
```